# I am getting the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" and Im not able to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the script. I am dragging and dropping the file into the terminal when it asks for input

```
print("Dictionary File Path -")
filename = input()

print("Words Length -")
word_length = input()
words = list()

with open(filename) as dict:
    for line in dict:
        if len(line) == word_length:
            list.append(line)
    print(words)
```

I am expecting the file to go through the text file and store the words in a list and print it out and also save it in another text file.

Comment: Obviously the filename you entered doesn't exist.

Comment: @Matthias I am dragging and dropping the file into the terminal, I wouldn't have been able to do that if the file didn't exist.

Comment: print the filename variable after the input line to see what you're getting.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, It is printing it correctly. "/e/_Projects/dictionary/popular.txt"

Comment: If it is in the E drive, then i think it should be E:/_Projects...

Comment: What if you hard-code the path? Also, please strip your code to a [mcve] when posting. If opening the file fails, the rest isn't executed and thus irrelevant to the question.

Comment: How about moving the file in the same directory as where you are running the script? Maybe from the script, that E:/ path is not accessible.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, sorry if I didnt follow any standards here. This is my first time writing python code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vas pointed out. The issue was in the directory string. I had to replace "/e/" with "E:/"